# Ace-editor focus / blur methods apparently not works integrated with termlib.js

Tags: javascript, focus, blur, ace-editor

Im developing a project were i need ace-editor integrated with terminal emulator; all problems
are exemplified [here](http://jsfiddle.net/34EaM/12/)

The problems lacks when human interaction fails: a user hoven on terminal and editor until he exit page. I want to set .focus() on "hoved" element and .blur() to "not hoved" element. To terminal, works ok, bot ace-editor fails on focusing. I can't be able to push some chars on editor.

Apparently jquery not works here:

```
$('#terminal').hover(function(){
  TermGlobals.setFocus(true);
}, function(){
  TermGlobals.setFocus(false);
})

$('#coffee_editor > textarea').hover(function(){
  window.editor.focus();
}, function(){
  window.editor.blur();
})
```

Someone have an clear idea why it isnt work properly?

Thanks for anything

## RESOLVED!

I remember [RTFM](http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/readme.txt)

```
7.2  TermGlobals.keylock (Global Locking Flag)

The global flag `TermGlobals.keylock' allows temporary keyboard locking without any
other change of state. Use this to free the keyboard for any other resources.
(added in v.1.03)
```

So I added the following in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34EaM/13/):

```
$('#terminal').hover(function () {
    TermGlobals.keylock = false;
    term.focus();
}, function () {
    TermGlobals.setFocus(false);
});

$('#coffee_editor').hover(function () {
    TermGlobals.keylock = true;
    window.editor.focus();
}, function () {
    window.editor.blur();
});
```

What's weird is that [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34EaM/13/) isnt working properly, but in [my project](https://github.com/jahpd/yaknowboutblogmusic/blob/master/app/helpers/terminal/builder.rb) works very well. Im running a Rails server, while jsfiddle runs inside `<iframe>`; why this difference in work?

Answer (score 1):

ace doesn't have any visible textarea attach listener to the container element instead.

```
$('#coffee_editor').hover(function(){
   window.editor.focus();
}, function(){
  window.editor.blur();
})
```

Comment: Mmm... maybe its sounds true; i edited src to http://jsfiddle.net/34EaM/11/; but isnt work properly yet: when i type some chars in keyboard, it do not appear in ace. I some way, editor is blocked, when terminal isnt; blinks in two windows works properly.

Comment: jsfiddle seems to be down atm, so i can't check, but i saw it yesterday. Set break on error and debug it.

Comment: In `console` i get this errors when i click on terminal: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` **VM369:1** -> `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)` **VM370:1** -> `Terminal.prototype.globals.activeTerm._cursorBlink()` `document.getElementById("SL_tocurlng").innerHTML=document.getElementById("SL_lng_to").options[document.getElementById("SL_lng_to").selectedIndex].text`; Also Lines in VM change everytime

Comment: I meant debug it, not tell me the error:). Anyway, apparently termlib.js you are using is very buggy and stops all the events in the page. Use `TermGlobals.setFocus({lock:1});` instead of `TermGlobals.setFocus(false);` to trick it to not consume all events.

Comment: I resolved the issue in my project just minutes ago... (jsfiddle is weird...) see my own answer on SO question; in your opinion, are there differences between my solution and your? anyway, i'm very greatfully for your help!

Comment: it checks for several things in keydown handler and any of them would work. I'd prefer {lock:true} solution since it is shorter and keeps handling of terminal in one place.